# A statement following from the law of excluded middle

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Does the statement ~~$A\equiv A$ follow from the law of excluded middle?
 According to my book which is not on logic it does, but I do not know how to use the law of excluded middle for this simple tautology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $A$ and $\neg A$. Then $A\land \neg A$, which is absurd, hence $\neg\neg A$. So $A\implies \neg\neg A$: this holds without the law of excluded middle.

Now assume $\neg\neg A$. If $A$, then $A$. 
If $\neg A$, then $\neg A\land \neg\neg A$ which is absurd, hence $A$.

So whether $A$ holds or $\neg A$ holds, we always get that $A$ holds : thus [it's this "thus" that uses the law of excluded middle] $\neg\neg A\implies A$

Comment: Thanks for your complete illustration

Comment: You should probably add that you are using the principle of explosion, if not it is not explicit how you go from "which is absurd" to "hence A". It turns out that you cannot get DNE (double-negation elimination) from LEM without EX (explosion), even though we can get both LEM and EX from DNE over the other standard rules.

Comment: @user21820 : explosion is a standard rule, isn't it ?

Comment: Well... it is of course standard in classical logic, but here we are obviously talking about weaker systems than classical, so that you can investigate the relation between DNE and LEM over those weaker systems. If you look at a Fitch-style system, you see that the rules for $\land,\to$ are like definitions of one-line/expanded forms, rather than assumptions. And the rules for $\lor$ are quite natural if you treat $\lor$ as meaning branching (such as via game semantics). $\neg,\bot$ are different though, so I think it is better to explicitly state the rules for them that are involved here. =)

Comment: @user21820 : surely for weaker systems it is useful to state that; but it is standard in intuitionistic logic  as well for instance, which is (it seems to me - but I get your point) what the question seemed to be aiming at

Comment: Yup it is a standard rule in intuitionistic logic. But I could probably be quite confident that the asker does not know what is intuitionistic logic. =)

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that one reason for my comments is that many typical Fitch-style systems for classical logic have DNE but no LEM or EX, and of course one of the first things you do is to recover LEM and EX, but that immediately raises the question of whether you could replace DNE by LEM, and the answer is "no" because LEM by itself is not 'enough'.

Answer (score 3):

An informal argument showing that $\lnot \lnot A \equiv A$ follows from the law of excluded middle is the following: by the law of excluded middle, either $A$ or $\lnot A$ holds, there is no third option. So, $\lnot \lnot A$ (whose truth value is determined by the truth value of $A$) should be equivalent to either $A$ or $\lnot A$. Since $\lnot \lnot A$ is the negation of $\lnot A$, it is impossible that $\lnot \lnot A$ and $\lnot A$ hold at the same time and hence they are not equivalent. Therefore, $\lnot \lnot A$ is equivalent to $A$.

Comment: Why talk about "equivalent" ?

Comment: @Max - What is wrong with the word "equivalent"?

Comment: Well, I agree that it's true in classical logic, but a priori why should the LEM imply that $\neg\neg A$ is equivalent to $A$ or $\neg A$ ? Moreover, it's not really what matters: it's not important that $\neg\neg A$ is equivalent to $A$ or to $\neg A$

Comment: @Max: The question asks whether $\lnot \lnot A$ is equivalent to $A$.  Depending on how you state it, one formulation of the law of the excluded middle says that each statement is either true or false - there is no "middle". This is why the rule is called "tertium non datur" after all. So, in any model, $A$ and $\lnot A$ have opposite truth values, and the question is whether $\lnot \lnot$ has the same truth value as $A$ or as $\lnot A$. Since $\lnot A$ and $\lnot (\lnot A)$ have opposite truth values, $A$ and $\lnot \lnot A$ must have the same truth value.

Comment: @CarlMummert : yes, sure, that's why this answer is not wrong; but I still don't really feel it's necessary, useful, or pedagogical for that matter, to talk about "equivalent". But indeed, this is correct (perhaps this is more semantics-oriented, while my answer is more syntax-oriented ?)

Comment: @Max Yes, I would think of this as a more semantic (and also more informal, but those are independent properties) argument.

Comment: The interesting thing to me is that the two answers use different viewpoints. They could be looked at as syntactic and semantic. It also strikes me that the first answer could be viewed as looking at LEM as the ability to assume $A \lor \lnot A$, which is a useful way to look at LEM in the context of constructive mathematics (where we might know LEM holds for some particular statement, and want to use that). The second answer could be viewed as looking at LEM in terms of two-valued semantics, where LEM says that negation is an involution on truth values.

Comment: @CarlMummert : I totally agree with your last comment as well; perhaps my first comments were too harsh - it is indeed a different viewpoint

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't clear.  Is the question "Can (~~A≡A) follow from the law of the excluded middle" the answer is 'yes'.  That follows immediately from every single tautology implying every other tautology.  Or equivalently, "all tautologies imply every other tautology."

However, if the question is "does the law of the excluded middle necessarily imply (~~A≡A)", where "imply" gets understood to mean that the law of the excluded middle will appear in any proof of (~~A≡A) where (~~A≡A) is not an axiom, then the answer is 'no'.  As a simple example, (~~A -> A) and (A -> ~~A) along with modus ponens and ((A -> B) -> ((B -> A) -> (A ≡ B))) will imply that (~~A ≡ A).  There is no law of the excluded middle there, and (~~A≡A) is not an axiom.

Comment: I got reminded of the proverb of the centipede who forgot how to walk when asked to explain exactly how it dealt with so many legs (a remark in the same book where my question arose from)